# Android Cache folder is created as file

Tags: android, caching

I am using Disk Cache folder for storing image files. It works perfectly, but after anyone performs Clean Data from his/her device the cache folder turns into a file.

Here is the code for creating cache directory

```
File myDiskCacheDir=getDiskCacheDir(this,IMAGE_CACHE_DIR);

diskCache=new MyDiskCache(this,myDiskCacheDir);


public static File getDiskCacheDir(Context context, String uniqueName) {
            if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||(!isExternalStorageRemovable()))
        {
            cachePath=getExternalCacheDir(context).getPath();

        }
        else {
            cachePath=context.getCacheDir().getPath();
        }

        new File(cachePath).mkdirs();

        return new File(cachePath + File.separator + uniqueName);
}


public static File getExternalCacheDir(Context context) {
    if (Utils.hasFroyo()) {
        return context.getExternalCacheDir();
    }

    // Before Froyo we need to construct the external cache dir ourselves
    final String cacheDir = "/Android/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/cache/";
    File cacheDirFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + cacheDir);
    cacheDirFile.mkdirs();
    return cacheDirFile;
}
```

I am facing this problem in Android 4.2 and below only.

Comment: Actually after clear data it is not even creating the parent directory of the cache directoty (i.e. returned from context.getPackageName(), say com.example.app

Comment: is the issue found in ExternalCacheDirectory or CacheDir ?

Comment: ExternalCacheDirectory

Comment: We tested your code in android 5.0 and it is working fine. It is deleted both package and cache directory when we click on Clear Data under application information.

Comment: I'm facing this problem in android 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
new File(cachePath + "/").mkdirs();
```